# How to maintain the state of widget in ListView?

Tags: listview, flutter, state

I have a list of clickable widgets[i.e MarkWidget] when the widget is clicked the state of widget is changed. But when the list is scrolled to the bottom and scrolled back to the top all widget's state is reset to default.

How do I stop/force flutter to not redraw the existing widget in the list after scroll?

For Example : 
if I click on ITEM 1 is color changes from green to red but if scroll to the bottom and scroll back to top the ITEM 1 color changes back to green.
I need the ITEM 1 color to be red if it is clicked irrespective of scrolling.

[image: DEMO]

Here is code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        platform: TargetPlatform.android,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<Widget> _widgetList = List.generate(
    30,
    (index) => MarkWidget(
          key: Key('ITEM $index'),
          title: 'ITEM $index',
        ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("My List"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        key: new Key("my_list"), //new

        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return _widgetList[index];
        },
        itemCount: _widgetList.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MarkWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MarkWidget({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MarkWidgetState createState() => _MarkWidgetState();
}

class _MarkWidgetState extends State<MarkWidget> {
  bool _checked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          _checked = !_checked;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(5.0),
          ),
          color: _checked ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
        ),
        child: Text(
          "${widget.title}",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            decoration: _checked ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : TextDecoration.none,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Add the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` mixin to your `State` of your `StatefulWidget` (Item widget), override the `wantKeepAlive` method and return `true`.

```dart
     class _MarkWidgetState extends State<MarkWidget> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin{
       ...

         
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      // call this method.
      super.build(context);
      ...
    }

     @override
       bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
     }
```

More info here: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html

Comment: I always wondered, in this situation lets say that the items selected were very high so lots of states kept alive and user scrolled up, down. Doesnt this use lots of memory to keep the states?

Comment: you are totally right [cs-guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9570941/cs-guy), it will load all that widgets on memory

Comment: Will setting `wantKeepAlive` keep the widget loaded or just save its state and rebuild it when the user scrolls back to it? If the widget stays loaded then what's the difference between that override and just using a `ListView()` instead of a `ListView.builder()` after the override?

Comment: @Hady  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3v4ZofYsn5I  enable english subtitles

Answer (score 5):

If you don't explicitly need a `ListView.builder`, an option would be to change your `ListView` for a `Column` and wrap it inside a `SingleChildScrollView`. The `Column` will preserve the state of your widgets (because it does not load them lazily, like the `ListView` does). That way you can avoid having to make your widgets make use of `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`, which is also correct, but a different approach. It just depends on what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Now, how about PageStorageKey?

```
    ListView.builder(
    key: const PageStorageKey<String>("my_list"), //must be unique

    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return _widgetList[index];
    },
    itemCount: _widgetList.length,
  ),
```

The PageStorageKey will preserve the state of each item when scrolling up and down.

look the PageStorage class at official [Flutter website](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageStorage-class.html)

Comment: Automatically it stores only a scroll offset state (see ScrollPosition) in Scrollable widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes just increase the cacheExtent value

```dart
 ListView(
  cacheExtent: 2000,
 ...
```