# StatefulWidget gets disposed on navigation

Tags: flutter

I have a stateful widget MyList that contains ListView. On tapping on any list tile the new screen (MyScreen) opens and after coming back (by pressing back button on top left) the scroll position is lost because MyList gets disposed and initState runs again. How can I prevent MyList from disposing?

```
class MyList extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyListState createState() => new _MyListState();
    }

class _MyListState extends State<MyList> {
  List<String> items = new List.generate(20, (index) => 'Hello $index');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Scrollbar(
        child: new ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return new ListTile(
              title: Text(items[index] + ' index $index'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => new MyScreen(index),
                    ));
              },
            );
          },
          itemCount: items.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is MyScreen:

```
class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int indx;
  MyScreen(this.indx);
  _TaskDetailState createState() => new _TaskDetailState();
}

class _TaskDetailState extends State<MyScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Text('yoba'),
      ),
      body: Text('yoba ${widget.indx}'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55699781/how-to-maintain-the-state-of-widget-in-listview/55699865#55699865

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a [PageStorageKey](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageStorageKey-class.html) to your ListView widget.

```
class _MyListState extends State<MyList> {
  List<String> items = new List.generate(20, (index) => 'Hello $index');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Scrollbar(
        child: new ListView.builder(
          key: PageStorageKey("MyList"), // <-- Add this line
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return new ListTile(
              title: Text(items[index] + ' index $index'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => new MyScreen(index),
                    ));
              },
            );
          },
          itemCount: items.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it seems like a workaround, but doesn't work accurately and doesn't answer the question: How to maintain state of the stateful widget?

Comment: This isn't a workaround, using a PageStorageKey is the recommended way of maintaining scroll position. If this doesn't fix your issue then the problem is probably caused by a widget further up the widget tree causing its children to rebuild.

Comment: When I add scrollListener and generat new list items and populated items with them and saved them in state with setSate and when state gets disposed then items list refreshes.