# Elements are not built in right way in ListView

Tags: flutter

I want to output all elements of snapshot.data.berichte in a ListView in a Card. My problem is that two elements are built(what is right), but the first element is built twice. So the loop is not counted up actually.

Here is my code snippet:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.data.berichte.length; i++) {
              return ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data.berichte.map((item) {
                if (item.team == team) {
                  return Container(
                    width: 500,
                    height: 500,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    child: Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                      elevation: 5,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                            child: Text(
                              DateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm").format(
                                  DateTime.parse(
                                      snapshot.data.berichte[i].spielDatum)),
                              style: TextStyles.body,
                            ),
                          ),                      
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                            child: Text(
                              snapshot.data.berichte[i].ueberschrift,
                              style: TextStyles.headline4,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),

                            /*   width: 350,
                                      height: 800, */
                            child: Text(
                              snapshot.data.berichte[i].bericht,
                              style: TextStyles.body,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              }).toList());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is an easier way to achieve what you want, without using a for-loop.

The example below shows you how ListViews are generally used. The standard ListView constructor works well for small lists. To work with lists that contain a large number of items (or if you want to optimize re-rendering in your viewport), it’s best to use the ListView.builder constructor.

Using the example below, replace the `items.lenght` with `snapshot.data.berichte.length`. As your Card is more complex you also might want to outsource it into a custom widget (just as a tip). To get your Cards just return them and access the index via `snapshot.data.berichte[i]`.

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
             ...,
            );
          },
        ),
```

Comment: You could also add to your answer the following (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55699865/15782390) if OP would like to preserve the state of the widgets (if he has a small list) as `ListView.builder()` only keeps visible widgets alive as you said in your post.

Comment: @Hady I don´t see the point using the referenced approach for a small list, as this is the use of the normal ListView constructor.

Comment: The `ListView()` widget takes in a `children` parameter. If you don't have a set list of widgets but want to build them with a function which iterates over them similar to what a `ListView.builder()`'s `builder` parameter does, then that might be better than making a `for` loop that returns a list. It also could be that the app might have a setting to keep all widgets loaded or not to allow a variety of devices with varying hardware (which performs differently) to use the app without any performance issue while the developer wouldn't need to develop two widgets (such as ListView and builder).